# Intel ARC intel-i915-dkms dpkg error upgrading to HWE kernel 6.5

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

Whenever I try to install something, it returns this error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libegl-mesa0:amd64 (24.1~git2402200600.41cd32~oibaf~m) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                   Setting up libegl-mesa0:i386 (24.1~git2402200600.41cd32~oibaf~m) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:amd64 (24.1~git2402200600.41cd32~oibaf~m) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:i386 (24.1~git2402200600.41cd32~oibaf~m) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.38-1ubuntu6.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic
 linux-headers-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also can't install from a .deb which returns the error "cannot satisfy dependencies"

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a ; sudo apt install -f` gives this:

```
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic (6.5.0-17.17) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-17-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
cp defconfigs/i915_only .config; 'make' -j22 KLIB=/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic olddefconfig; 'make' -j22 KLIB=/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/intel-i915-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-17-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/intel-i915-dkms/1.23.9.11.231003.15/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-17-generic/x86_64 failed for intel-i915-dkms(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-17-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic
 linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic (6.5.0-17.17) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-17-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
cp defconfigs/i915_only .config; 'make' -j22 KLIB=/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic olddefconfig; 'make' -j22 KLIB=/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/intel-i915-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-17-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/intel-i915-dkms/1.23.9.11.231003.15/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-17-generic/x86_64 failed for intel-i915-dkms(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-17-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                   Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic
 linux-headers-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using this PPA. https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers. You could try removing that PPA to get back to stock Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem is with the `linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic`. I suspect the nvidia drivers broke. Please [edit] with the full error message above or when you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a ; sudo apt install -f`. @popey The mesa from that PPA installed successfully.

Comment: @DanielT i have added the full code when running `sudo dpkg --configure -a ; sudo apt install -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the wrong kernel version (6.5 HWE vs 5.x non-HWE) and the intel-i915-dkms kernel module. It is only necessary and compatible with 5.x kernels.

```bash
sudo -i

dpkg --force-all -P intel-i915-dkms
dpkg --configure -a

apt update
apt install -f
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade

apt purge intel-i915-dkms
apt purge dkms
apt autopurge
apt clean
```

The updated i915, modules should be included by default on 6.5. If you don't have Intel ARC, you can skip this step. Reboot and check if your GPU is still fast in games. If not, we can roll back to 5.x:

```bash
# Only necessary if your Intel ARC doesn't work without intel-i915-dkms.
# If your GPU works fine now,
# then skip this and remove the added Intel repository instead.

sudo -i

apt install linux-generic
apt purge linux-generic-hwe-22.04
apt autopurge
apt install intel-i915-dkms
reboot
```